# algorithm for combining smaller tiles to balance the bigger ones

Tags: algorithm

I have a field of tiles - basically each tile is a country that has some kind of sovereign. The tiles - countries - have different weight. For now I use some numerical value but in the future the weight will depend on tile size, produced resources and so on.

So I want for those countries to make alliances if their sole weight is much lower - or at least lower than a certain threshold - than the weight of the neighborhood tile (each sovereign is basically a primitive AI at that stage that is able to make decision to create the alliance). Here is couple of scenarios

[image]

Here are the examples for bigger maps with possible *alliances*

[image]

So my question is - is there some kind of algorithm that allows to achieve that or I have to create it myself or use training sets for AI to gain the ability to form alliances?

Comment: Looks close to the [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is NP-hard. A bit harder to be precise since the bin size is not fixed.

Comment: @wondra quite possible. need to dig into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem is the similar to Bin packing problem mentioned by @wondra. 
Here is the definition of bin packing problem

```
Given a multiset S = { s1, s2..., sN } of N elements and a bin
capacity C, all positive integers, the bin packing problem is
to separate the elements of S into as few subsets (bins) as
possible, such that the sum of each subset is no greater than C
```

The definition of my problem is

```
Given a multiset S = { s1, s2..., sN } of N elements and number C,
all positive integers, my problem is to combine elements of S
into a few subsets, such that the sum of each subset is no
much greater than C (or possible threshold)
```

They are indeed similar